# Kendo Grid Foreign Key column shows blank cell

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Kendo Grid Foreign Key column shows blank cell

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<Doc.Web.Models.Vendor.DocumentsDetails>)Model.documents_lst)
    .Name("grid").Scrollable()

    .Columns(columns =>
    {

        columns.Bound(o => o.DocumentRevisionID).Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Documentnumber).Title("Document #").Width(150);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Revision).Title("Revision").Width(80);
        columns.Bound(o => o.RevisionDate).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Title("Rev Date").Width(85);
        columns.Bound(o => o.RevisionStatus).Title("Revision</br> Status").Width(100);
        columns.ForeignKey(o => o.DocNumberPurpose, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Purpose"], "Value", "Text")
                .Title("Purpose");


    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(o => o.DocumentRevisionID))
    )

    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(5)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.DocumentRevisionID))
        .Read(read => read.Action("EditingInline_Read", "DesignCoverSheet").Data("additionalInfo"))
    )
     )
```

In controller I have the below code which creates the viewBag

```
ViewBag.Purpose = rep.ReadPurposeList(Convert.ToInt32(site), 5, "TR");// returns a Select List
```

I also have the GridForeignKey View inside editor templates folder

```
@model object

@(
 Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)        
        .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])

)
```

Comment: You are binding your `ForeignKey` column to `ViewData["Purpose"]`, but setting the data in `ViewBag.Purpose`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve the data from **ViewData** if you setting the data to **ViewData** in the controller